# JSON: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting this error **Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0** from yesterday and yet not solved.

This is my jquery

```
$("body").on("click", "input.add", function(event) {

    var myData = {"p":'Hello'};
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myData);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'test2.php',
        data:{'mydata':myJSON},
        dataType:"json",
        cache:false,
        success: function(result){
            $(".message").html('SUCCESS: '+result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions , thrownError){
            $(".message").html('ERROR: '+thrownError);
            console.log("Data: "+thrownError);                  
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

This is my PHP code:

```
header('Content-Type:application/json');
var_dump(json_decode($_POST['mydata']));

if(isset($_POST['mydata'])){
    echo 'found';
}
else
    echo 'Not found';
```

Please help me where am i doing wrong, where is my error, what should i change?

Comment: `stripslashes` the mydata

Comment: did any ans worked for you ?

Comment: @Rishi No ans worked yet

Comment: try to comment php header also ? just try to print `found` or `not found`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning string and set as json remove this line

```
  dataType:"json",
```

Also comment var dump from ajax response

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the JSON type data using `$_POST`, for this you have to useL

```
$paramsStr  = file_get_contents('php://input');
$params     = json_decode($paramsStr, true);
```

Comment: If I use this code then I am getting unexpected token N in Json at position 0

Comment: Still this issue is open ?